# Wifi stops working when computer is inactive

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

Allow me to elaborate.

I went out to the store today, and I closed my laptop before I left.  When I got back, I opened my laptop and suddenly it won't detect any wifi networks at all.  It starts working again if I restart my computer, but I had to do this twice today.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?  I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Thank you in advance.